# difficulty displaying API response in redux-react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

halo guys, so i'm using redux-react for the first time and i'm getting my data from the api, but i'm having issue displaying them in my browser, can anyone help out
below are my code sample

##slice file

```
export const fetchUserArticle =createAsyncThunk(
    'article/get-article-user',
    async(id, thunkAPI)=>{
        try{
            const response = await dataService.getUserArticles(id)
            thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(response.msg))
            //thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(response.data.msg))
            return response
        }
        catch(err){
            const message = (
                err.message && 
                err.response &&
                err.response.message
            ) || err.response ||
            err.toString()
            thunkAPI.dispatch(setMessage(message))
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue()
        }
    }
)
```

### index.js file

```
const UserAticles = (props)=>{
    const [articles, setArticle] = useState([])
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    let article = []

    useEffect(()=>{
        getUserArticle()
    
    },[])


    const getUserArticle =() =>{
        const id = user._id
        dispatch(fetchUserArticle(id))
            .unwrap()
            .then((res) =>{
                article = res.data
                setArticle(articles, res.data)
            }
            
        )
        console.log(articles)

    }
```

so when i console API res, i see it in my console, but when i try using saving in a variable with useState it doesn't save, so i can't access the response in my template
pls can anyone help out?

Comment: If you want to use a variable to store the response data,  you should use `const article = useRef([]);`, otherwise, when the component re-render, it will create a new `let article = []` variable when the `UserAticles` execute again. The `article` data will become `[]`. And for the `articles` state, in the current call stack of `getUserArticle`, it's `[]`, you should log it in the component function scope, when the component re-render, the `articles` state will be the response data

Answer (score 0):

When you update the state please use only ,

```
 article = res.data 
 setArticle(article)
```

.You have already set the **articles** variable here in the state

```
const [articles, setArticle] = useState([])
```

So you can get the articles by ,

```
console.log(articles)
```

Comment: it didnt wrk, when i console or try 2 access d variable in my template, it return empty array

Comment: Pls add your reducer file on the code

Comment: the first code is my reducer

Comment: it should an action file , not reducer